# Macbook pro 2018 overheating when connected to external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought 2018 Macbook Pro the same day connected to LG external monitor 4k. It had overheat and noisy to luckily its withing cooling period so Apple replaced it. 
I ran and running just two application one is google (gmail) and another one youtube 4k test video (LG 4k external monitor). After 40 minutes its quite hot in the above touch bar and both the speaker side.. Now I am unable to use the external monitor.
Please let me how to fix this issue!

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Based on your explanation, I think the best thing to do is take it back to Apple.

Comment: Are you able to connect your MacBook to any other external monitor? (With the same port).

Comment: Hi Naveed, thanks for reply.  I haven't tried because don't have another external monitor. Looks like the Mojave causing the issue. My wife have same MacBook Pro that doesn't get overheat after 2 hours though. But her MacBook os is High Sierra.

Comment: Hi fsb, Thanks. Apple diagnostic using their software but no issue found. So they also don't know the reason.